# Cocoapods framework not found - mixed objective c and swift pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, onesignal

**tl;dr;** how to use old (what shouldn't use `use_frameworks!`) and new  pods together in podfile?
I had working podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

    target 'myApp' do
        pod 'Alamofire', '1.3.1'
        pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
    end
```

Then I added `OneSignal` pod according to documentation [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/installing-the-onesignal-ios-sdk)
So my pod file changed to:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myApp' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '1.3.1'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
    pod 'OneSignal'
end
```

I updated pods and run build - got error:

```
ld: framework not found OneSignal
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked `OneSignal` pod and it looks differently compared to others:
[image]
Thats probably because is old style objective-c framework.
I can add this framework manually to my project but I wonder how to make it work properly with cocoapods? 
This issue relates to my problem I think https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3338

---

Update
I'm currently using Xcode 6.4

Comment: you can see this might will  help you : [https://medium.com/@stigi/swift-cocoapods-da09d8ba6dd2](https://medium.com/@stigi/swift-cocoapods-da09d8ba6dd2)

Answer (score 2):

What version of Xcode are you using?

If update to the latest release versions of both Alamofire and SwiftyJSON and build with Xcode 7 it should fix your build errors.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myApp' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.0'
    pod 'OneSignal'
end
```